# Microsoft Edge localhost apache NTLM always try to auth against computername instead of localhost

Tags: apache, microsoft-edge, ntlm

I currently test NTLM authentication with Apache 2.4 on a windows machine, locally. All work fine. If i open a demo site `http://localhost/authfoo/text.php`, the site will load without an authentication dialog in every browser. The `test.php` script get all required authentication data automatically from the current windows user.

So far so good. Tested with Internet Explorer 11, Chrome, Firefox and it works. Only Microsoft Edge open up an authentication dialog and i must enter credentials. All what i see in this dialog window is that the title show my computername instead of `localhost`. This indicated that Edge use the computername as internal domain, and that is for sure no `intranet` domain, like `localhost` is.

[image]

There is something for edge that is a so called `LoopbackExempt`. With that you can allow `localhost` to be threaded as an `intranet` site. This setting also not helped me. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/#how-can-i-debug-localhost

However, when i manually add `http://15031489-nb.cstp.intern/` to intranet sites via settings in Edge, than it work when i use `http://15031489-nb.cstp.intern/authfoo/text.php` without an authentication dialog. But `http://localhost/authfoo/text.php` still show that authentication dialog.

Btw, `http://localhost` is also added to intranet sites, just to make sure everything will be treated as an actual `Intranet Site`.

So, i have no idea of how i can get this thing to work in Edge also, like every other browser already does, even IE 11 work without flaws.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching this problem for a while and found this answer from the microsoft developer community:

> Microsoft Edge doesn't allow integrated Windows Auth over loopback as
>   a security mitigation to prevent breaking the browser sandbox. The
>   only workaround offered by the team is to use the FQDN while
>   debugging.

([Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75716/debugging-with-microsoft-edge-prompts-for-credenti.html))

So you will have to use the FQDN instead of `http://localhost/`, which is `http://15031489-nb.cstp.intern/` in your case. I don't believe that Microsoft will ever fix this issue in Edge, as it is intended behaviour.